# Show there exist p such as $Kerf \varsubsetneqq Kerf^2\varsubsetneqq ...\varsubsetneqq Kerf^p=Kerf^{p+1}$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let E a finite dimensional vector space ($dimE = n \in \mathbb{N^*}$) and $f\in \mathcal{L}(E)$

How to show that there exist $$p\in [\![0,n]\!] \ \text{ such that:} \ \{0\}\varsubsetneqq Kerf \varsubsetneqq Kerf^2\varsubsetneqq ...\varsubsetneqq Kerf^p=Kerf^{p+1} \ ?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that otherwise you would have an **infinite nested sequence** of subspaces, each one with at least one dimension less than the previous one, which is impossible because of the finite dimension of space $E$.

(I assume that, besides, you know how to prove that for any $k$,  $Kerf^k \subset Kerf^{k+1}$ ).

Comment: So, I have to prove that by a Reductio ad absurdum?(I've shown what Adren told me to show) I've some difficulties to formalize the proof.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

You can show that :

1. For all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $\ker(f^k)\subset\ker(f^{k+1})$
2. For all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, if $\ker(f^k)=\ker(f^{k+1})$ then $\ker(f^{k+1})=\ker(f^{k+2})$